# Append java static variables

Tags: java, static

I want to append list of elements to next list array, here are code example:

```
public class AuthoritiesConstant {

    public static List<String> USER_ROLES = Arrays.asList("authenticated", "user", "article:read", "article:offer");
    public static List<String> MODERATOR = Arrays.asList( "moderator", "article:create", "article:update", "article:approve");
    public static List<String> ADMIN_ROLES = Arrays.asList("admin", "article:delete");


    AuthoritiesConstant() {
        // Each role get previous role authorities
        MODERATOR.addAll(USER_ROLES);
        ADMIN_ROLES.addAll(MODERATOR);
    }
}
```

When I use in code `ADMIN_ROLES` variable only two roles are registered: `"admin", "article:delete"`.

How can I append roles from previous role to next. So that `moderator` has all `user` roles, and `administrator` all `moderator` roles?

Comment: The list from `Arrays.asList` is fixed length: it doesn't supposed `addAll`. Also a constructor is not a suitable place to initialise static variables.

Comment: you shouldn't do that in your constructor. If you do, you'll be adding those values each time you create a new instance, sooner or later, that 'll give trouble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
    public static final List < String > USER_ROLES, MODERATOR_ROLES, ADMIN_ROLES;

    static
    {
        USER_ROLES = List.of( "authenticated" , "user" , "article:read" , "article:offer" );

        List < String > mod = new ArrayList <>( USER_ROLES );
        mod.addAll( List.of( "moderator" , "article:create" , "article:update" , "article:approve" ) );
        MODERATOR_ROLES = List.copyOf( mod );

        List < String > admin = new ArrayList <>( MODERATOR_ROLES );
        admin.addAll( List.of( "admin" , "article:delete" ) );
        ADMIN_ROLES = List.copyOf( admin );
    }
```

## Cannot add to fixed-size list

As [khelwood commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453580/append-java-static-variables#comment117480622_66453580), the [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a fixed-size list. You cannot add or delete elements.

We have a more modern alternative for a compact literal declaration of a [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) in Java 9 and later: `List.of`.

```java
List < String > furryAnimals = List.of( "dog" , "cat" ) ;
List< String > featheredAnimals = List.of( "cockatiel" , "canary" ) ;
```

You can make a modifiable list from those unmodifiable lists by passing them to the constructor and methods of other `List` implementations.

Here we instantiate a modifiable `ArrayList` object. In the constructor we pass one unmodifiable list. Then we add the contents of a second unmodifiable list by passing to `addAll` method.

```java
List< String > allCreaturesGreatAndSmall = new ArrayList<>( furryAnimals ) ;
allCreaturesGreatAndSmall.addAll( featheredAnimals ) ;
```

You can make an unmodifiable list by passing the modifiable one to [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) in Java 10 and later.

```java
List < String > animals = List.copyOf( allCreaturesGreatAndSmall ) ;  // Make an unmodifiable list of a modifiable list.
```

See also the [correct Answer by M A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66453752/642706) for other issues.

By the way, in Java conventions, we use all-uppercase only for constants. Your lists are changing, so names such as `USER_ROLES` should be `userRoles`.

### Constants

If you did indeed intend for those lists to be constants, those lists should be:

- Unmodifiable
- Declared `final` so no other object can be later assigned.

Your code might look something like the following.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Authority
{
    public static final List < String > USER_ROLES, MODERATOR_ROLES, ADMIN_ROLES;

    static
    {
        USER_ROLES = List.of( "authenticated" , "user" , "article:read" , "article:offer" );

        List < String > mod = new ArrayList <>( USER_ROLES );
        mod.addAll( List.of( "moderator" , "article:create" , "article:update" , "article:approve" ) );
        MODERATOR_ROLES = List.copyOf( mod );

        List < String > admin = new ArrayList <>( MODERATOR_ROLES );
        admin.addAll( List.of( "admin" , "article:delete" ) );
        ADMIN_ROLES = List.copyOf( admin );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "USER_ROLES = " + USER_ROLES );
        System.out.println( "MODERATOR_ROLES = " + MODERATOR_ROLES );
        System.out.println( "ADMIN_ROLES = " + ADMIN_ROLES );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
USER_ROLES = [authenticated, user, article:read, article:offer]
MODERATOR_ROLES = [authenticated, user, article:read, article:offer, moderator, article:create, article:update, article:approve]
ADMIN_ROLES = [authenticated, user, article:read, article:offer, moderator, article:create, article:update, article:approve, admin, article:delete]
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the lists are static members, so the user of your class is not expected to invoke the constructor, hence will not see the modifications to the lists (and in any case the modification of adding elements will throw an error because `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list).

You can do the concatenation inline with the member declarations, using the stream API to concatenate two lists:

```
public static List<String> MODERATOR = Stream.concat(USER_ROLES.stream(),
            Arrays.asList( "moderator", "article:create", "article:update", "article:approve").stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
public static List<String> ADMIN_ROLES = Stream.concat(MODERATOR.stream(),
            Arrays.asList("admin", "article:delete").stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```